# Store instances of classes in Python in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to store the instances of the class `Job` in a dictionary. I want to achieve something like this `{location : "London" ,  fee:500,fee:1200,location:"London" }`.  I tried the solution below by saving the entries in a class variable, but I can only get the value. I cannot define the key.

```
class Job:
    instances = dict()
    rate = 1.04

    def __init__(self, location, salary, description, fee)  :     
        self.location = location
        self.salary  = salary
        self.description  = description
        self.fee  = fee
        self.instances[self.location] = location
        self.instances[self.fee] = fee

    def Charge(self):
        self.fee = int( self.fee + Job.rate)



Job1 = Job("london",23000,"Accounts Assistant",1200)
Job2 = Job("london",25000,"Accounts Assistant",500)

print(Job.instances)
```

output:

```
{1200: 1200, 'london': 'london', 500: 500}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, location, salary, description, fee)  :
    self.location = location
    self.fee  = fee
    self.instances[self.location] = location
    self.instances[self.fee] = fee
```

Here you are setting the key `self.location` to `location`, which has the same value. That is why each key/value pair is repeated. Use `self.instances["location"] = location` to set the key `"location"` to the value of `location`, and the same for `fee`.